# How to configure sub-domains on Apache so as to point another web-app or a directory ; with tomcat on backend

Tags: apache, tomcat, amazon-web-services, subdomain

I am using AWS. I got an AMI which had apache, tomcat, mysql stack. Apache was connected fine with tomcat using ajp. How do I configure sub-domains like images.xyz.com ( which should point to a directory on Ubuntu server ), test.xyz.com ( which should point to another webapp running on tomcat ) on apache ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really had a tough time to figure this out and finally had to take help of my friend.

Modify file $APACHE/sites-available/default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName test.xyz.com
   ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/test
   ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName images.xyz.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/share/uploads
   <Directory "/usr/share/uploads">
        Options Includes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
         Order allow,deny
      Allow from all
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Note that in @Deepak's example, the use of the context-path `/test` may or may not be desirable. If you want your URLs to appear to be `http://test.xyz.com/something.jsp` than you are better-off deploying your Tomcat webapp as `ROOT.war` so it has a context path of "" (that is, an empty string, accessible on `/`). If you want a context path of `/test/`, then you should `ProxyPass /test ajp://localhost:8009/test` to avoid the pains of having to rewrite URLs generated from within your webapp that doesn't know about the reverse proxy's URL mangling.

Comment: The idea was that my main website will be on xyz.com ( this will be deployed as ROOT.war) ; while testing website will be text.xyz.com ( i can deploy my test war file as test.war ). If I would not have created this sub-domain above; then for testing the website I would always have to use xyz.com/test and I will end up re-writing lots of URL etc. test.xyz.com gives me the same contextPath as for root.war

Comment: FWIW, it's best to write your webapp in such a way that it *can* be re-located in this way. Our main webapp gets deployed to a number of different context-paths and works no matter what they are called: there is no additional configuration necessary (for us) to make this work.